# Change a number corresponding to change in another number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, numbers, logic

Lets say i have 6 entry of data i want to save to mysql, I have **4 entry as entry A with one billNo(eg:3)** and two other with another BillNo. ie,(entry A : Billno = 3, entry B: Billno = 5).

What I want is to billno change corresponding to sql,
-max(billno) in mysql is 15.

- i want to change the billno of entry A from 3 to 16(max(billno) in sql+1) and
- entry B to 17
  and same goes to entry C,D......

I have given some php code to demonstrate it

```css
public function saveIntransactionOne() {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            if (isset($_POST["salesIntransItems"]) and isset($_POST["intranscount"])) {
                $json = $_POST["salesIntransItems"];
                $json1 = $_POST["intranscount"];
                $BillNo = $this->model_mobileapi->getInvNoIntrans();
               if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                   $json = stripslashes($json);
               }
                $data = json_decode($json);
                $a = array();
                $b = array();
                $newBill =  $data[$j]->inv_no;
                  
                if ($_POST['code'] == 1) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                    $res = $this->model_mobileapi->saveintrans($data[$i]->itemname, $data[$i]->qty, $data[$i]->rate, $data[$i]->total, $data[$i]->party, $data[$i]->net_qty,$data[$i]->net_amnt,$data[$i]->godown, $data[$i]->employee, $data[$i]->date1, $newBill, $data[$i]->local_app_user_entry_id,$data[$i]->credit,$data[$i]->inv_no_str,$data[$i]->type);
                        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->local_app_user_entry_id;
                        $b["party"] = $data[$i]->party;
                        $b["status"] = 'uploaded';
                        array_push($a, $b);
                }
                echo json_encode($a);
                }
            }
            }else {
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Something went wrong";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

->  $BillNo = $this->model_mobileapi->getInvNoIntrans();   *is the mysql max(billno)*

->  $newBill =  $data[$j]->inv_no;   *is the incoming billno of entry*

**I hope you understand my Question, And i will provide any answer regards to this question.**

**Thank You**

Comment: why tag this as java?

Comment: sorry my bad, I took a random tag.

Answer (score -1):

Well i got the answer for that though. Little tricky but works excellent!!

```css
 public function saveIntransactionOne() {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            if (isset($_POST["salesIntransItems"]) and isset($_POST["intranscount"])) {
                $json = $_POST["salesIntransItems"];
                $json1 = $_POST["intranscount"];
               if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                   $json = stripslashes($json);
                   $json1 = stripslashes($json1);
               }
                $data2 = json_decode($json,true);
                $data = json_decode($json);
                $data1 = json_decode($json1,true);
                // echo json_encode($data1);
                $a = array();
                $b = array();
                for( $z = 0; $z < count($data1) ; $z++){
                $BillNo = $this->model_mobileapi->getInvNoIntrans();
                if ($_POST['code'] == 1) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                    if ( $data2[$i]["inv_no"] != $data1[$z]["inv_no"]) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                    $res = $this->model_mobileapi->saveintrans($data[$i]->itemname, $data[$i]->qty, $data[$i]->rate, $data[$i]->total, $data[$i]->party, $data[$i]->net_qty,$data[$i]->net_amnt,$data[$i]->godown, $data[$i]->employee, $data[$i]->date1, $BillNo, $data[$i]->local_app_user_entry_id,$data[$i]->credit,$data[$i]->inv_no_str,$data[$i]->type);
                        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->local_app_user_entry_id;
                        $b["party"] = $data[$i]->party;
                        $b["status"] = 'uploaded';
                        array_push($a, $b);
                }
            }
                echo json_encode($a);
            }
            }
            }else {
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Something went wrong";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```